# Wit.ai node package buggy

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, chatbot, wit.ai, facebook-messenger-bot

I was working with wit.ai today. I was using the `node-wit` module. But the responses I was acting were very weird.

When I used the `node-wit` module. I got the response as -

```
{
    "msg_id": "0f4rOWRXQMIhVuf5i",
    "_text": "what is your name",
    "entities": {
        "intent": [{
            "confidence": 0.9425254893432,
            "value": "get_name"
        }]
    }
}
```

Whereas when i used the cURL command to get the response the response was very different.

```
{
    "msg_id": "0KJdIPedYbYwWOgOL",
    "_text": "what do you do",
    "entities": {
        "intent": [{
            "confidence": 0.97713342030998,
            "value": "get_job"
        }]
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell why this is happening or if I am implementing the function wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same service, there are two services, one for conversations/stories and other for messages.

if that is not the reason try to check the context and take a look on the log section inside wit.ai web app

[image: WIT.AI]

Comment: how to use node-wit for messages?